# _OBJC_TAG_MASK in currently open sourced OC Runtime is weird

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I'm reading the OC Runtime source code from [here](https://github.com/RetVal/objc-runtime), especially about Tagged Pointer.

What trouble me is the way Runtime decide the value of 
_OBJC_TAG_MASK.

```
#if OBJC_MSB_TAGGED_POINTERS
#   define _OBJC_TAG_MASK (1UL<<63)
#else
#   define _OBJC_TAG_MASK 1UL
#endif
```

The OBJC_MSB_TAGGED_POINTERS defined as follow

```
#if TARGET_OS_OSX && __x86_64__
    // 64-bit Mac - tag bit is LSB
#   define OBJC_MSB_TAGGED_POINTERS 0
#else
    // Everything else - tag bit is MSB
#   define OBJC_MSB_TAGGED_POINTERS 1
#endif
```

Which essentially means

```
#if TARGET_OS_OSX && __x86_64__
    // 64-bit Mac - tag bit is LSB
    // We know that we have 64 bits and use LSB?
#   define _OBJC_TAG_MASK 1UL
#else
    // Everything else - tag bit is MSB
    // Won't this be problematic on 32 bits iOS 
devices?
#   define _OBJC_TAG_MASK (1UL<<63)
#endif
```

I'm really puzzled, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's quite simple, Tagged Pointers are 64 bits only feature currently.

```
#if __LP64__
#define OBJC_HAVE_TAGGED_POINTERS 1
#endif

#if OBJC_HAVE_TAGGED_POINTERS

// All related codes here.

#endif
```

When it comes to MSB and LSB

- TARGET_OS_OSX && **x86_64**: The LSB will guarantee to have at least 4 bits available since malloc will return 16-byte aligned memory address.
- Otherwise: ARM64 only use 48 bits out of 64 bits, so the MSB is wasted anyway, move MASK to MSB seens quite reasonable.

Comment: 0

Do you know why they don't just also use the LSB for taggin on ARM64 to keep things consistent since I assume malloc on iOS will also return 16 (or at least 8 byte) aligned addresses?